# Plotting a function handle of two variables

Tags: matlab, function-handle

I have the following code:

```
f1_p1 = @(xq1) interp1(x_j1,p1,xq1);
f2_p1 = @(xq2) interp1(x_j2,p1,xq2);
new_p1x1 = @(xq1,xq2) f1_p1(xq1).*f2_p1(xq2);
```

To plot `f1_p1` and `f2_p2` is easy, I do:

```
fplot(f1_p1, [30,70])
```

**My question**

How can I plot the second function (`new_p1x1`)? I have tried the same as before but it doesn't work....(`fplot(new_p1x1, [30,70])`) I get:

```
Error using @(xq1,xq2)f1_p1(xq1).*f2_p1(xq2)
Not enough input arguments.
```

Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using

```
fplot(new_p1x1, [30,70])
```

**[30,70]** is considered as 1x2-matrix and thus only as one argument, while **new_p1x1** requires two. Thus you can call either

```
new_p1x1(30, 70) # 30 is passed to f1_p1 and 70 to f2_p2
```

or

```
new_p1x1([30,70], [30,70]) # The matrix [30,70] is passed to both function.
```

I cannot tell, which solution is more useful for you, it depends on what you want to to.

However, it seems, fplot only accepts functions with one argument. So it seems, you have to use one of the 3D plotting functions.

For 3D plotting, you can use e.g. `surf`.

```
[x1,~] = fplot(f1_p1, [30,70]); % Returns a useful number of x-values for f1
[x2,~] = fplot(f2_p1, [30,70]); % Returns a useful number of x-values for f2

[X,Y] = meshgrid(x1,x2);

surf(x1,x2,new_p1x1(X,Y)); % x1 (X) is passed to f1, x2 (Y) is passed to f2
```

Comment: I have problems using a 3d plotting for functions in matlab. Could you help me with this! It is so frustrating... I have tried `ezplot(fy1,[30,70])` but it returns a plot of `xq1 vs. xq2`...  I have also tried `ezplot(fy1,[30,70],[30,70])` but the result is the same...

Comment: I have added some code for 3D plotting. Please tell if this is the plot you need.

Comment: That's good. Sorry for the confusion in my first version of the answer.